# How to get a string from a bytes array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, byte

I'm creating my own DNS server and host blocker, I want to get host from DNS request message `byte[]`

dns message hex dump:

```
e07901000001000000000000057961686f6f03636f6d0000010001
.y...........yahoo.com.....
```

code:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string b64 = "4HkBAAABAAAAAAAABXlhaG9vA2NvbQAAAQAB";
        int pad = b64.Length % 4;
        if (pad > 0 )
        {
            b64 += new string('=', 4 - pad);
        }
        byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(b64);
        int start = 13;
        int end = start;
        while(decoded[end] != 0){
            end++;
        }
        
        int hostLength = end-start;
        byte[] byteHost = new byte[hostLength];
        Array.Copy(decoded, start, byteHost, 0, hostLength);
        string host = Encoding.Default.GetString(byteHost);
        Console.WriteLine(host); // yahoo♥com
    }
}
```

The questions:

1. is my method above to get host name right/efficient/fastest ?
2. why I get weird character replacing the dot `yahoo♥com` ?

change to Encoding.ASCII or Encoding.UTF8 has no effect

Comment: For reference: it can be interesting to write a DNS server as an academic exercise, but I wouldn't do this for "real things" - just get a pi-hole; it has custom host blocking inbuilt, etc

Comment: it for learning  

Comment: Does using this matches your goal and provides the excpected result: `new string(decoded.Select(b => (char)b).Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray())` ? You can replace `IsLetterOrDigit` by any logic.

Comment: @OlivierRogier it will remove the dot.

Comment: @uingtea Your code outputs `yahoo♥com` and the snippet `àyyahoocom`. What do you expect in fact ? `yahoo.com` ?

Comment: the problem is, there is strange character replacing the dot `.` it need to be valid domain like `yahoo.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, `03` is not `ETX` but length of the next string, let see the the example

```
00 05 79 61 68 6F 6F 03 63 6F 6D
.  .  y  a  h  o  o  .  c  o  m
```

`05` mean is the length of `yahoo` and `03` is for `com`

Valid host or domain name contains only ASCII range from 44-127 or `[a-z0-9-\.]`, domain like `bücher.nu` will be converted into `xn--bcher-kva.nu`, so I replace byte like `03,0C,09` or under 44 with the dot `.`

and thanks to @Marc Gravell for `GetString(decoded, start, hostLength)`

```csharp
/*
I0sBAAABAAAAAAAABmMtcmluZwZtc2VkZ2UDbmV0AAABAAE
ldgBAAABAAAAAAAABWZwLXZwCWF6dXJlZWRnZQNuZXQAAAEAAQ
4HkBAAABAAAAAAAABXlhaG9vA2NvbQAAAQAB
*/
string b64 = "4VoBAAABAAAAAAAAIGYyNWIzNjgyMGUyNDljNGQxY2I0YzQzNGUxNjc5YTljA2Nsbwxmb290cHJpbnRkbnMDY29tAAABAAE";
int pad = b64.Length % 4;
if (pad > 0)
{
    b64 += new string ('=', 4 - pad);
}

byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(b64);
int start = 13;
int end = start;
while (decoded[end] != 0)
{
    if(decoded[end] < 44)
        decoded[end] = 0x2e;
    end++;
}

int hostLength = end - start;
string host = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decoded, start, hostLength);
Console.WriteLine(host);
```

edit: micro optimization, benchmark with 1e9 or 1 billion loop

`Convert.ToChar()` finished in 00:00:04

```
for(int i =0; i<1e9; i++){
    while (decoded[end] != 0)
    {
        if(decoded[end] < 44)
            decoded[end] = 0x2e;
        host += Convert.ToChar(decoded[end]);
        end++;
    }
}
```

VS `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` finished in 00:03:20 (200 seconds)

```
for(int i =0; i<1e9; i++){
    while (decoded[end] != 0)
    {
        if(decoded[end] < 44)
            decoded[end] = 0x2e;
        end++;
    }
    int hostLength = end - start;
    string host = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decoded, start, hostLength);
```

Answer (score 5):

1. There's no need for the second array; `Encoding.GetString` allows you to pass in an offset and count, so: `GetString(decoded, start, hostLength)`
2. *Never* use `Encoding.Default`; that is badly named - it should be called `Encoding.Wrong` :) Find out what encoding the data is in (probably UTF-8 or ASCII), and *use that*
3. You should be able to use `IndexOf` to find the terminating `'\0'`; also consider what your code should do if it doesn't find one

As for the unusual character: the data contains an `03` byte where you would expect the `.`; check the DNS protocol specification to see if this is expected. `03` is `ETX` (end of text). Beyond that: I don't know.

Comment: thanks, about `IndexOf` i try `Array.IndexOf(decoded, (byte)0);` but it return 3 not 18

Comment: @uingtea you can provide the start offset too